# How to return method value to it's origin in C#

Tags: c#, methods, return

In this example, I have 3 values which are used by a method in a class.

Main Method:

```
String testString;
List<String> testList = new List<String>(){
   "Value1",
   "Value2",
   "Value3",
}
int goGet = 2;

TestClass.DrawString(testString, testList, goGet);
```

The class:

```
class TestClass
{
    public static void DrawString (String myString, List<String> myList, int get){
       myString = myList.ElementAt(get);
       get = get + 1;        
    }
}
```

I want to know  if I can return the values to their original place (i.e. myString to testString, myList to testList, and get to goGet) within the class,and if so how.

Comment: Why are you passing in "myString" instead of having the return type of DrawString be string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a  look at using [ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
>   value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the
>   parameter in the method is reflected in the underlying argument
>   variable in the calling method. The value of a reference parameter is
>   always the same as the value of the underlying argument variable.
>
> To use a ref parameter, both the method definition and the calling
>   method must explicitly use the ref keyword
>
> An argument that is passed to a ref parameter must be initialized
>   before it is passed. This differs from out parameters, whose arguments
>   do not have to be explicitly initialized before they are passed.

So change the method signature to

```
public static void DrawString (ref String myString, List<String> myList, ref int get)
```

and the calling statement to

```
TestClass.DrawString(ref testString, testList, ref goGet);
```

Comment: Worth noting that the difference between `int` and `List` is one is a primitive and the other is an object.